# ASP.NET How to handle User Control Event in page that contains the User Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, event-handling

I have a page that that contains a User Control and a submit Button. The User Control contains a Drop Down List.

I want to make the Button on the page visible if the user selects an item in the User Control's Drop Down List.

How can I make the page recognise the Drop Down List `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add own `event` to your UserControl and subscribe on it in page's code-behind. In `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler fire your event if somebody subscribe on it. Detailse explanation with code you may find here: [Easily Raise Events From ASP.NET ASCX User Controls](http://codebetter.com/brendantompkins/2004/10/06/easily-raise-events-from-asp-net-ascx-user-controls/)

Answer (score 3):

Expose a custom public event in your user control - MySelectedIndexChanged. Subscribe to this event in your page class. Effectively delegates and events.

Read more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)